# how to Remove default added classes from quasar vue components?

Tags: javascript, jquery, quasar

In my quasar project, I am using the q-option-group component. when I checked it in the dev tools it shows one class added q-gutter-x-sm by default. because this class adds extra blank space on the right side of the div. So I want to get rid of that class. How can I achieve this?

my code is:

```
<div class="col col-12">
   <q-option-group
     v-model="selectedFeature"
     :options="featureOptions"
     inline
     type="checkbox"
     color="primary"
     class="margin-none"
    />
 </div>
```

it is rendered as:

```
<div class="margin-none q-option-group q-gutter-x-sm q-option-group--inline" >
   all options
</div>
```

so it adds **q-gutter-x-sm** class which I want to remove. How to do that?

Comment: The styling may depend on the parent element. See [Quasar docs: Grid Gutter](https://quasar.dev/layout/grid/gutter#pros-cons-and-how-to-workaround-problems-q-gutter-size-vs-q-col-gutter-size)

Comment: I haven't  applied q-gutter anywhere in the code. And when I deleted 'q-gutter-x-sm' in dev tools it is working as expected. So I want to remove this class from my code.

Comment: You can look at the [Quasar examples for q-option-group](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/option-group). If the gutter is not there it probably comes from somewhere in your code. If you want a workaround anyway, you can also add scoped CSS which overrides padding/margin as you want.

Comment: Thanks @PeterKrebs for replying so quickly. But It's not the issue of margin and padding.

Comment: I mean whatever blank space you must get rid of you can override the CSS if you must use a workaround anyway. Have you checked the Quasar examples? I don't think they output grid classes, so there must be something in your app which causes them.

Comment: Every time I am using that q-option-group component it adds q-gutter-x-sm. I want it to be removed.

Comment: If you will inspect any option group from quasar examples, you will see q-gutter-x-sm class there.

Comment: Oh you inspected the examples? Have you noticed they do not have an extra blank space to the right? Just follow their template code and classes they use. They want you to use gutter, so learn it instead of avoiding it.

Answer (score 0):

To solve my blank space on right side issue I used the following code instead of q-option-group.

```
<div class="row">
   <div
    class="col col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-1"
    v-for="option in featureOptions"
    :key="option.value"
   >
   <q-checkbox
     v-model="selectedFeature"
     :val="option.value"
     :label="option.label"
   />
  </div>
</div>
```

But I couldn't figure out how to remove that class. So if you know the answer kindly share.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in the q-option-group component the `class="q-gutters-x-none"` like so:

```
<div class="col col-12">
 <q-option-group
  v-model="selectedFeature"
  :options="featureOptions"
  inline
  type="checkbox"
  color="primary"
  class="q-ma-none q-gutter-x-none"
 />
</div>
```

Note that I also replaced the class `"margin-none"` with Quasar helper class `"q-ma-none"`. This should be just enough to remove the unwanted space.